# Swift cellforrow load asynchronously

Tags: uitableview

When i load data array into uitableview cellforrow, how can i make it show only in top most visible cell first? Each custom cell is just over half size screen and when user scrolls, it changes the top most visible to next one. The code is what i am currently using

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId,
             for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
  let task = 
self.data[indexpath.row]
    
  cell.taskTitle.text = task.title
  cell.taskNote.text = task.note
  return cell
```

Comment: The issue is not related to this code.

Comment: @vadian i was asking for how should i implement? Sorry for confusion